# ACF: Creating Custom Field Type store two values

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom field type that can store my value in an array.

Everything works fine, however I created another input and pass the value as $field['additional_text'] however this updates ['value'] rather than ['additional_text'].

Array
(
    [value] => X
    [additional_text] => Y
)

How do I target the correct key to pass the values to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is when you're creating your fields form inputs the name of the field must be as follows: -

```
name="<?php echo esc_attr($field['name']) ?>[value_x]"

value="<?php echo esc_attr($field['value']['value_x']) ?>"

name="<?php echo esc_attr($field['name']) ?>[value_y]"

value="<?php echo esc_attr($field['value']['value_y']) ?>"
```

This will allow you to store multiple values in your custom field type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ACF's](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) get_field() and [update_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) function to get and set the value.
You can also manipulate the field with get_post_meta() and update_post_meta() function.

Actually ACF store two values for each meta field.
For example if I added 'price' custom field with ACF then 'price' and '_price' 2 post meta fields are created in database.
As you know meta_key that has underscore prefix is not listed on edit post page
Here real value is saved in 'price' field.

Comment: Hmmm, when I tried this, using update_field() it only updates the value key not the additional_text key value.